# I have a duplicate row problem in jquery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a duplicate row problem in jquery datatable. Some rows show in more than one page when get Jquery datatable by ajax call :

[image]

[image]

I used this query..... how can I fix this bugs and can I use unique() method?

```
var data = (from h in db.TwitterTrends
                        select new
                        {
                            h.Id,
                            h.Name,
                            h.TweetVolume,
                            Countries = h.TwitterTrendCountryRelations.Select(Country => Country.Country.Name).Distinct(),
                            h.LanguageCode,
                            Categories = h.TwitterTrendCategoryRelations.Select(Category => Category.Category.Id).Distinct(),
                            h.Url,
                            h.IsPublished,
                            CategoryName = h.TwitterTrendCategoryRelations.Select(Category => Category.Category.Name),
                            TrendDate = h.TwitterTrendCountryRelations.OrderByDescending(b => b.TrendDate).FirstOrDefault().TrendDate,
                            HashtagStory = h.HashtagStory
                        });
 data = query.OrderByDescending(h => h.TrendDate).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize)
//jquery datatable
  var RequestVerficationToken = $('input[name = "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        $("#Twitter-List").dataTable({
            "bSort": false,
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "pageLength": 10,
            "oSearch": { "sSearch": Searchvalue },
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                $(".select2").select2({
                    placeholder: "Please select",
                    width: 175,
                });
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("LoadDataTable")",
                "datatype": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": { __RequestVerificationToken: RequestVerficationToken }
            },
            "columns":
                [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "TweetVolume" },
                    { "data": "Countries" },
                    { "data": "LanguageCode" },
                    {
                        "render": function (row, data, type, full, meta) {
                            var Options = "";
                            $(CategoryOptions).each(function (i, item) {"...."}
```

Comment: You need to share your code and explain the issue with little more details.

Comment: Also, share your API code, where you load data. 90% that your API returns duplicated data.

Comment: I have shared my code   @ChetanRanpariya  ,,,

Comment: @Alex-TinLe this code i'm used

Comment: how do you calculate the "skip" param in your API? Can you share all code of that action.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe this way

`var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0].ToString();
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

From you shared code, the skip is calculated wrongly

```
var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0].ToString();
int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
```

It should be

```
int skip = (start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0) * pageSize;
```

Because, when your pageindex is 0, you need to skip 0 row. When your pageindex is 1, you need to skip 20 rows (assume that your page size is 20).

Comment: it is wrong way because skip will double first time will skip 10 records second time will skip 100 records third 200 as will as

Comment: i found the problem when i'm using .Distinct(), method inside the query